# While chmod 'ing for htdocs. I found daemon user. Who is this?

Tags: permissions, users, htdocs

I am new to ubuntu. Recently I tried to change user of htdocs according to many q&a 's available on askUbuntu. I followed these steps:

```
qayyum@qayyum:~$ who am i
qayyum   pts/0        2014-10-01 15:29 (:0)
qayyum@qayyum:~$ sudo chown -R qayyum:qayyum /opt/lampp/htdocs
qayyum@qayyum:~$ sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

As stated in many answers it worked well. But in file `/httpd.conf`I found users which are not assumed to be there.
**Problem** 
 These users were found:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

instead of suspected:

```
User nobody
Group nogroup
```

**Is it ok to chang it to my user name and nogroup?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it it is ok to change. Some configuration files may bring some variables like that, they're just examples. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed `apache httpd` from source and the user by default is given as `daemon`. It doesnt matter what user you run apache with, just make sure that user has required permissions in the `RootDirectory`

Comment: I have installed xampp which includes apache I think.

Answer (score 0):

Abdul, If you are trying to fix permission of Htdocs In Ubuntu, following this instructions may be helpful: http://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-in-ubuntu.html
Hope it works!

Comment: It is 2017 now! Welcome to SO/AU btw

Comment: Oops, I didn't pay attention to the date, my fault, I am sorry. Thanks anyway for the welcoming.